# Order alphabetically some items (not all) on an Enum

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an Android app and I have this enum that is going to be shown in a Spinner ordered alphabetically using `statureString`.

```
public enum Stature
{
    noSelected (-1, MSDApplication.getAppContext().getString(R.string.no_selected)),
    tall (0, MSDApplication.getAppContext().getString(R.string.stature_tall)),
    average(1, MSDApplication.getAppContext().getString(R.string.stature_average)),
    small(2, MSDApplication.getAppContext().getString(R.string.stature_small));

    private final int stature;
    private final String statureString;

    Stature(int anStature, String anStatureString) { stature = anStature; statureString = anStatureString; }

    public int getValue() { return stature; }

    @Override
    public String toString() { return statureString; }

    public static Stature[] getSortedVaules()
    {
        Stature[] statures = values();
        Arrays.sort(statures, EnumByToStringComparator.INSTANCE);
        return statures;
    }
}
private static class EnumByToStringComparator implements Comparator<Enum<?>>
{
    public static final Comparator<Enum<?>> INSTANCE = new EnumByToStringComparator();

    public int compare(Enum<?> enum1, Enum<?> enum2)
    {
        return enum1.toString().compareTo(enum2.toString());
    }
}
```

And here is how I add set this enum as an ArrayAdapter for a `Spinner`:

```
private void setSpinStatureData()
{
    mSpinStature.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Stature>(mActivity, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, Stature.getSortedVaules()));
}
```

As you can see the first item on the Enum is `noSelected` and I need that this must always the first item on the Spinner, and the next will be ordered alphabetically.

I use `statureString` because this var is going to be localized.

**How can I do to make noSelected to be the first item?**

Comment: You can use a list or an array! instead of a enum, may be??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [Lesleh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17262981/order-alphabetically-some-items-not-all-on-an-enum/17263018#17263018) answer, I did this:

```
private static class EnumByNameComparator implements Comparator<Enum<?>>
{
    public static final Comparator<Enum<?>> INSTANCE = new EnumByNameComparator();

    public int compare(Enum<?> enum1, Enum<?> enum2)
    {
        if (enum2.toString().equals(MSDApplication.getAppContext().getString(R.string.no_selected)))
            return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        else if (enum1.toString().equals(MSDApplication.getAppContext().getString(R.string.no_selected)))
            return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        else
            return enum1.toString().compareTo(enum2.toString());
    }
}
```

I have several `Enums` all of them with `noSelected` item, and now I can use this comparator with all of them.

And also, I compare with `toString()` because I set `Enum`'s `Description` localized.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a comparator that takes the noSelected case into account, and makes it always less than whatever it's compared to.

```
private static class StatureComparator implements Comparator<Stature>
{
    public static final StatureComparator INSTANCE = new StatureComparator();

    public int compare(Stature first, Stature second)
    {
        if(first == Stature.noSelected)
            return -1;
        else if(second == Stature.noSelected)
            return 1;
        else
            return first.toString().compareTo(second.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've been testing it and `noSelected` is always on `second` enum.

Answer (score 0):

a) Obvious, but it is so obvious that I must print it. Make your `getSortedValues()` method just return a copy to an already sorted array.

```
public Stature[] getSortedValues() {
  if (mySortedArray == null) {
    mySortedArray = new Stature{noSelected, small...}
  }
  return mySortedArray.clone();
}
```

b) Implement a `java.util.Comparator` that defines the ordering that you want and use it instead of `EnumByToStringComparator.INSTANCE`